# How do I use additional rubygems inside a custom Cloud Foundry buildpack?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm writing a customized java-buildpack, and I'd like the ability to edit the web.xml file to add some required configuration.  However, I seem to be limited to only the rubygems that are present on the instance node, which does not include any XML parsing libraries.

How can I have the buildpack specify that it needs an additional gem to execute?  Adding gems to the Gemfile in the buildpack itself doesn't seem to have any effect when staging an app.

Alternatively, how can I modify an existing XML file with only the stock facilities available in CF?  I wanted to avoid a regex, but that may be a last resort.

Comment: Turns out I can use the REXML package for XML manipulation, which is available in the staging container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, I seem to be limited to only the rubygems that are present on the instance node, which does not include any XML parsing libraries.

Correct.  When your build pack runs in the staging container, it's going to use the version of Ruby provided by the container.  This means that you are locked into a specific version of Ruby and the set of gems provided by the container.

The only way around this would be to have a bootstrap shell script that downloads Ruby, installs your Gems, and then runs the actual build pack Ruby scripts.  It's a lot of extra work and overhead though, so probably not a good option if you can avoid it.

> How can I have the buildpack specify that it needs an additional gem to execute? Adding gems to the Gemfile in the buildpack itself doesn't seem to have any effect when staging an app.

I don't think that this is possible.  You can't `gem install` something because it would require root access, and you won't have that.

What you could do instead is to include the dependencies that you need in the build pack.  We did that with a YAML dependency for the PHP build pack.  If your dependency is all Ruby code (i.e. no native code), this should work OK.

> Alternatively, how can I modify an existing XML file with only the stock facilities available in CF? I wanted to avoid a regex, but that may be a last resort.

It depends on what you're doing and what you need to change.

- Regex search and replace is an option.
- Basic string search and replace is another.
- You could shell out to a tool that's installed in the environment and is capable of parsing / editing the XML
- If it happens later in the install after Java has been installed, you could run some Java code.

I would not recommend creating a custom stack.  It's incredibly invasive, means you then need to provide all updates going forward (not a small task), and it's not something that will work if you're going to use a public cloud provider, since no one is going to allow you to install your custom stack in their public cloud.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks!  Very informative, and supports what I discovered through more testing today.  I determined that the REXML package is available in the staging container, and was able to write some basic code to do what I want.

For the curious, I needed to insert some custom servlet filters at the top of the web.xml file, so that they are guaranteed to be first in the filter chain.

Comment: Very useful comment, thanks!

Not sure if it can be of any use in your case, but I have noted that we can configure java buildpack to use external Tomcat configuration per https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/blob/master/docs/container-tomcat.md#external-tomcat-configuration.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom stack (container root fs) with all required libraries for this purpose.

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/stacks.html

https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/custom-stack.html

Comment: Thank you, I had not seen those guides before.  However, I would not have any control over the container FS, only the buildpack.  I discovered that ruby does include an XML parser in the base install, and I didn't need to figure out how to get nogojiri on the image.